# Creating C structs using the RubyInline gem

Tags: c, ruby

I've got a Rails app that needs to show the results of a Monte Carlo sim, and for the first time, Ruby just isn't fast enough for my needs. So, I started poking around to see if I could rewrite my simulation in C and use those results in Ruby, and some googling turned up the RubyInline gem for easily writing faster C code directly in Ruby. Doing simple stuff works great, for instance, some basic functions written in both Ruby and C:

```
class FasterFunctions
  inline do |builder|
    builder.c '
    double rand_sum(int trials)
    {
      double sum = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i<trials; i++)
      {
        sum += (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
      }
      return sum;
    }'

    builder.c '
    long loop_sum(long trials)
    {
      long sum = 0;
      for (long i = 0; i<trials; i++)
      {
        sum+=i;
      }
      return sum;
    }'
  end
end

#the C version is 4 orders of magnitude faster
trials = 1_000_000
ruby_sum = 0
trials.times {|i| ruby_sum += i}
c_sum = FasterRand.new.loop_sum(trials)

# the C version is 1 order of magnitude faster
ruby_sum = 0.0
trials.times {ruby_sum += rand}
c_sum = FasterRand.new.rand_sum(trials)
```

So, great, it should definitely speed up my sim since it's pretty much just generating random numbers and adding stuff up based on those results. Unfortunately, beyond basic stuff like this, I can't figure out how to actually write my program. I need to pass some structs around to act as state variables, so the first order of business is figuring out how to create a C struct. Reading [the documentation](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html), it seems like it should be fairly simple.

> accessor(method, type, member = method)
>
> Adds a reader and writer for a C struct member wrapped via
>   Data_Wrap_Struct. method is the ruby name to give the accessor, type
>   is the C type. Unless the C member name is overridden with member, the
>   method name is used as the struct member.
>
> ```
> builder.struct_name = 'MyStruct' 
> builder.accessor :title,        'char *' 
> builder.accessor :stream_index, 'int',   :index
> ```

The documentation isn't entirely clear to me, but I assume that I'd put that in a class much like before and do something like the following to access it:

```
class MyStructClass
  inline do |builder|
    builder.struct_name = 'MyStruct'
    builder.accessor :title, 'char *'
    builder.accessor :stream_index, 'int', :index
  end
end

#possible this
struct = MyStructClass.new.MyStruct
struct.title = 'A Title'

#or maybe
struct = MyStructClass.new
struct.title = 'A Title'
```

Unfortunately, I can't even get that far

> */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:456:3:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'MyStruct'   MyStruct *pointer;   ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:456:13: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   MyStruct *pointer;
>               ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:458:35: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   Data_Get_Struct(self, MyStruct, pointer);
>                                     ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1038:6: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
>        ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:458:25: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'MyStruct'   Data_Get_Struct(self, MyStruct, pointer);
>                           ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1038:15: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
>                 ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:458:3:
>   error: expected expression   Data_Get_Struct(self, MyStruct, pointer);
>   ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1038:20: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
>                      ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:460:23: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   return (rb_str_new2(pointer->title));
>                         ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:786:27: note: expanded from macro 'rb_str_new_cstr'
>       (__builtin_constant_p(str)) ?               \
>                             ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:460:23: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:787:14: note: expanded from macro 'rb_str_new_cstr'
>           rb_str_new((str), (long)strlen(str)) :  \
>                       ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:460:23: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:787:33: note: expanded from macro 'rb_str_new_cstr'
>           rb_str_new((str), (long)strlen(str)) :  \
>                                          ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:460:23: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:788:18: note: expanded from macro 'rb_str_new_cstr'
>           rb_str_new_cstr(str);                   \
>                           ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:460:10: error: returning 'void' from a
>         function with incompatible result type 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long')   return (rb_str_new2(pointer->title));
>            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:478:3:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'MyStruct'   MyStruct *pointer;   ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:478:13: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   MyStruct *pointer;
>               ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:480:35: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   Data_Get_Struct(self, MyStruct, pointer);
>                                     ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1038:6: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
>        ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:480:25: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'MyStruct'   Data_Get_Struct(self, MyStruct, pointer);
>                           ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1038:15: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
>                 ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:480:3:
>   error: expected expression   Data_Get_Struct(self, MyStruct, pointer);
>   ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1038:20: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
>                      ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:482:3:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   pointer->title = StringValuePtr(value);   ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:456:3:
>   error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'MyStruct'   MyStruct *pointer;   ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:456:13: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   MyStruct *pointer;
>               ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:458:35: error: use of undeclared identifier
>         'pointer'   Data_Get_Struct(self, MyStruct, pointer);
>                                     ^
>   */.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1038:6: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
>        ^ fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]

I've done a bunch of googling, but pretty much every example I've found deals only with the simple use case I outlined at first. The first error it spit out was that MyStruct was undeclared, so I tried adding a struct definition before the accessor methods, like so:

```
builder.c '
  typedef struct
  {
    char *title;
    int index;
  } MyStruct;
'
```

That doesn't do anything, and the documentation seems to be clear that the c method is only for declaring functions, not structs. I'm not really sure what to try next, does anyone else have some experience with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RubyInline seems to assume that you know your way around writing Ruby extensions if you are doing anything more complex than the basics.

You *do* need to define the struct yourself as you tried, but you should use the [`prefix` method](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-prefix) rather than the [`c` method](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-c) (which is for defining methods). You also need to define the allocation method for the class. You can do this with the [`c_singleton` method](http://docs.seattlerb.org/RubyInline/Inline/C.html#method-i-c_singleton) by adding a function named `allocate` which RubyInline will recognise and use as the allocation function (this doesn’t seem to be documented, I found it by looking at the source).

Putting it all together looks something like this.

```
class Foo
  inline do |builder|

    # First define the struct that will be wrapped in the
    # class.
    builder.prefix <<-DEFINE_STRUCT
      typedef struct {
        char* bar;
      } MyStruct;
    DEFINE_STRUCT

    # Next define the allocation function that will
    # allocate and wrap a MyStruct struct when creating a
    # new Foo object. You might want to initialize the values
    # to avoid possible segfaults.
    builder.c_singleton <<-ALLOCATE
      VALUE allocate() {
        MyStruct* pointer = ALLOC(MyStruct);
        return Data_Wrap_Struct(self, NULL, free, pointer);
      }
    ALLOCATE

    # Finally we can use the struct_name and accessor methods.
    builder.struct_name = 'MyStruct'
    builder.accessor 'bar', 'char *' 
  end

end
```

Note you can see the generated C code if you look under the directory `.ruby_inline` in your home directory.